# Axios - Sending a GET with & sign

Tags: axios

I have a GET call (/getTag) that has a variable 'name'.

One of my users created on with a & sign. And unfortunately the GET call is now failing because it looks like this.

> /getTag?name=IS&me-1234

Unfortunately my server interprets it like this because of the & sign:

> { id: 'IS', 'me-1234': '' }

Anyone experienced this before and have a way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on a variable `name` before passing it to `axios`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use params key in axios
`axios.get('/getTag', {params: {name: 'Is&me123'}})`

Answer (score 0):

You should request like:

```
axios.get('https://your-site.com/getTag', { params: { name: 'IS&me-1234' } });
```

instead of:

```
axios.get('https://your-site.com/getTag?name=IS&me-1234');
```